# jquery function adding html form with returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a US map and when someone clicks on a state it displays a form.  For example like below... this is a sample.  The problem is a few of the forms have over 15 form elements.  Adding those without returns is not manageable and very tedious to add without getting errors.

Is there anyway I can add a form to the code below and add the form with returns instead of without returns like the code below?

No Returns =  I mean adding each form element on one line without pressing enter on your keyboard ...

Returns =  Adding form element then pressing enter to go to the next line.

```
function myCallback(event, data)
  {
  if ('CA' == data.name) 
  {
    $('#notif').html('<form>First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\" "+ data.name +"  \"><br>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\" "+ data.email +" \"></form>');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but you can use basically two ways

*1. String manipulation*

In javascript there are two ways to break a long string, concatenation and using the \ character.

Example

**Concatenation:**

```
$('#notif').html(
      '<form>First name: ' +
          '<input type="text" name="name" value="' + data.name + '"\>' +
          '<br>Email:' +
          '<input type="text" name="email" value="'+ data.email +'"\>'+
      '</form>');
```

Basically you organize your strings to be more readable. Mind the use of `'` and `"` they can be used indistinctly but is better if you are consistent in which sign you use to enclose your strings and which to use for your attributes.

**Breaking long strings**

The [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) says that you can break a long string with a `\` sign

Example

```
$('#notif').html(
      '<form>First name: \
          <input type="text" name="name" value="' + data.name + '"\>\
          <br>Email:\
          <input type="text" name="email" value="'+ data.email +'"\>\
      </form>');
```

Is a bit harder to read but basically is the same using only one string.

*2. Using native elements*

You can also use jquery to create your form elements in a variable and attach them to the form using the append function

Example

**Using JQuery**

```
var container = $('#notif');
    container.append('<form></form>')
    var form = container.children('form');
    form.append('First name: ')
        .append('<input type="text" name="name" value="' + data.name + '"\>')
        .append('<br>Email:')
        .append('<input type="text" name="email" value="' + data.email + '"\>');
```

This function is chainable so you can have one element per line

Comment: You know I'm on here a lot reading posts and replies.  I've noticed I see this a lot -   "Your question is a bit unclear "   Now when I see these types of replies on other posts, I don't understand them because every time when I read a question I understand what the person is saying... my question is why do you not understand it?  I'm like really???

Comment: -- it's a bit unclear???  I purposely added the definition for No Return and Return so you and everyone else would be clear ... you know you hit the enter key to go to the next line .... not sure what's so unclear about that but so be it....   I would say to all that do not understand a question to read it again then maybe it will be clear.

Comment: The answer is ok. My 2nd question to you would be, as a programmer, would you want to add  ' ' + ' ' around 15 form elements?  A little cumbersome don't you think? The other examples are worse.

Comment: If you read your question again you will see that your answer is out of the scope of the question. You didn't  say anything about loading the form using ajax, which in my opinion is an overkill for what you want to accomplish. Concatenating string one of the most used and easiest ways to create dom elements. What you are forgetting is that ajax calls and dom manipulation are expensive operations and you are using both.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer to "MY" question that's so hard to understand.
Use .load( "form.php" )

```
$('#notif').load("form.php");
```